# Framelayout with two Elements

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout

I got a FrameLayout which has two elements, a TextView and a View with a Backgroundcolor.
Whithin eclips previw this shows up as expected, the view overlays the Textview.
Howewer when i am inflating this layout into another the colored view just disapears. any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp" android:background="#000" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@+id/viewActive"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the code for include

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
ViewGroup view2 = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout, null);
anotherViewGroup.addView(view2);
```

Comment: do you mean the TextView should overlay the View?  have you tried setting the TextView background color to transparent?

Comment: **Whithin eclips previw this shows up as expected** means in Graphical Layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Your plain view's width is set to "wrap_content". That means the view should be as big as my content but it doesn't have any content so the width is effectively 0, making it invisible.

Try setting the width to a hardcoded value like "10dp" or "match_parent". That should do the trick.